# Is it possible to have a state param that looks like a path with angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-ui-router

Here's an example with these two routes:

```
.state("test", {
  url: "/test/{path}",
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
})
.state("test.child", {
  url: "/child",
  template: "<p>child</p>"
})
```

The following urls would be valid:

- `/test/thing` would render `test`'s view and `$stateParams.path` is `"thing"`
- `/test/thing/other` would render `test`'s view and `$stateParams.path` is `"thing/other"`
- `/test/thing/child` would render `test.child`'s view and `$stateParams.path` is `"thing"`
- `/test/thing/other/child` would render `test.child`'s view and `$stateParams.path` is `"thing/other"`

I have tried using a regexp on the `path` param so that it would take any string except anything that ends in `"/child"`, but that would only redirect me to my default state since there is no match with the regexp.

My current workaround is to use another separator, such as `,` instead of `/` for my path param (gives me these kind of urls: `/test/thing,other/child`), and I'm gonna keep using that for now, but I was still wondering if anything of the sort was possible.

Comment: `$stateParams` are not inherited by children afaik. You could make them available via `resolve` instead. What wasn't working in your example?

Comment: If you were to reorder the routes such that the path `/test/child` came before the first route and was not a child of test (so you rename the state to `testChild` or some such) then the first route takes precedence over the second. If you're resolving things you'd have to resolve them again, but if you needed to you could make both children of test, so `test.main` and `test.child` and resolve all dependencies in the master route, just having a subroute for each and reordering. If you're ok with this, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("test-child", {
      url: "/test/{path:.*}/child",
      template: "<h1>CHILD's view</h1>"
    })
    .state("test", {
      url: "/test/{path:.*}",
      template: "<h1>TEST's view</h1>"
    })
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DTO8sNr67am07csFOxR9?p=preview